# How to include the same partial view more than once with Blade?

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

i'm building a web app with Laravel 4, and i want to build a custom control for tags selection like this one implemented in StackOverFlow, i have created a partial view which has the CSS files and JS files and the select control, i include it in my view it works great, the problem is that i have to use the same control twice in my view, one for tags and another for activities, so the problem is that if i include it twice, and JS files get loaded twice ! 
I want to use it like a widget, i can place it in any view and in the same view more than once !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Blade Partial views to make *Widgets*.
However, you should not load the *.css* and *.js* files within a *Widget Partial View* because, like you said, it will load the files more than once.

If you find yourself loading *.css* and *.js* files depending on the pages, you can add to your **main-layout.blade.php** (the file where you have your  tag something like this:

***File:*** *main-layout.blade.php*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
@if(isset($loadOnHead)) <!-- Check if $loadOnHead is defined to avoid errors -->
@foreach($loadOnHead as $file)
   {{ $file }} <!-- Output all the files on the array -->
@endforeach
@endif
</head>
<body>

   <!-- * Your Site/App Content * -->

   <!-- Call the widget-css-js.blade.php file,
        note that the contents won't be loaded here.
    -->
   <!-- * Your Widget * -->
   @yield('widget') 

   <!-- * Your Widget Again * -->
   @yield('widget') 

   <footer>
      <!-- You can do another @foreach here for a $loadOnFooter
           array if you want to load scripts on footer 
           (you should load .js on footer).
        -->
   </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

|

***File:*** *widget.blade.php*

```
<!-- Your Widget HTML and Code goes here -->
* Your Widget Content *
```

|

***Controller:*** *at your Controller, when you build the page with the widgets (NOT the Widgets itself), you should:*

```
public function MakeWidgetPage()
{
    //Add Scripts and CSS files to the Head
    $loadOnHead = array(

        HTML::script('js/app.min.js'),
        // Generates: <script src="http://your-app/js/app.min.js"></script>

        HTML::style('css/style.css'),
        // Generates: <link media="all" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://your-app/css/style.css">
        
    );

    //Response
    return View::make('page-with-widgets')
        ->with('loadOnHead', $loadOnHead);
}
```